# Sticky javascript when physically dragging to resize browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I have a function(s) that expand a drop down list when the browser is size n.

Size n is determined by css media queries and works as expected.

However when I physically drag the width of the browser window out, the .click function remains bound to the element even though a media query indicates that a css hover effect takes place when the browser is size n + 1.

A refresh at any point produces the desired behavior but of course I don't want to require a refresh.

```
   var section_4 = "#main-menu > li:nth-child(4) > a";
   var sub_section_4 = "#main-menu > li:nth-child(4) > ul";

    $( section_4 ).click(function() {
        $( sub_section_4 ).slideToggle(300);        
        return false;
    });
```

how can I apply this function only on a given size and not have the .click follow to the inline list ? thanks

Comment: You can set a handler on window.onresize event and if window.innerWidth = n  do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jquery [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [`.resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) like this:

```
var section_4 = "#main-menu > li:nth-child(4) > a";
var sub_section_4 = "#main-menu > li:nth-child(4) > ul";

var docWidth = (window).width();
$(document).resize(function(){
    docWidth = (window).width();    // Refresh value on resize
});

$( section_4 ).click(function() {
    if( docWidth < [integer] ){        // set integrer the same as your @media.
        $( sub_section_4 ).slideToggle(300);
        return false;
    }
});
```